# How to disable Opera alt button?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, opera, opera-10

How to prevent Opera from showing opera menu on alt button press?

Opera version: 10.60_pre6351, amd64, Gentoo (Linux)

The menu that I am talking about is this:

[image: Opera Menu]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

How you get there: `CTRL+F12` (or menu -> Settings -> Preferences)
Click Advanced tab, Shortcuts at the bottom (step 1 on pic);
Perform step 2 (click on edit on the shown part);
Type in: `tab`
Use the hit at the bottom..

(Okay forgot step 5: select it; step 6: click delete.)

Comment: Reserving the slot, hmm? ;) Good in my opinion, prevents duplicates.

Comment: Sorry I just wanted to take some time until the pro-paint picture is done. :-D (Don't know if one can do this, please say if its "illegal".)

Comment: I have deleted all keyboard shortcuts that I do not use. And this is definitely not related to «Address Dropdown widget».

Comment: However, I've tried that on mine, it still shows the menu on Alt.

Comment: Hmm I fear this one is a global shortcut (IE it works everywhere like in explorer (I'm on Win) and *maybe* it cannot be changed.)

Comment: Removed *ALL* the shortcuts from the options, everywhere, and it still works. Sorry that I wasn't much help.

Comment: I have tried to search in `opera:config` for keywords «menu», «alt», «meta» and some more, but it found nothing useful. Thought someone on superuser knows how is this option named.

Comment: @Shiki defining global shortcuts that are respected by all applications is not possible. Focusing menu using alt is just a convention respected by most Windows and some Linux GUI application developers. Sometimes this functionality is forced by the graphical toolkit, but not in case of new Opera, that uses its own GUI library.

Comment: If its possible to adjust. Check out forums (maybe you'll get an answer there faster): http://my.opera.com/community/forums/

Comment: Just ended pasting this question to that forum.

Comment: Yeah yeah I see the question. Wondering how could one solve this..

Comment: @Shiki - this is a global shortcut for the menus, yes. Normally (for example if you check show menu), it will highlight the "File" menu (and show shortcuts for other menus). However, this is something for sure made on the application side, this behavior, nothing forces Opera to behave this way, it's only a norm. However, I can't find as well a way to change this behavior.